# SQL: Create Trigger that automatically copies some values into another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I'm trying to write a trigger for MySQL, where it automatically inserts some attributes of the last row of a table called "Kurs" into another table via creating a new row.

The tables look like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE Kurs (
    KursNummer int, 
    Name varchar(255),
    Beschreibungstext varchar(255),
    Einschreibeschlüssel varchar(255) NULL, 
    Plaetze int,
    BenutzerErstellerNummer int,
    CONSTRAINT fk_BenutzerErstellerNummer
    FOREIGN KEY (BenutzerErstellerNummer) REFERENCES Benutzer(BenutzerNummer),
    PRIMARY KEY (KursNummer)
);

CREATE TABLE einschreiben (
BenutzerEinschreiberNummer int,
KursNummer int,
Eintrittsdatum date,
EinschreibeID int,
CONSTRAINT fk_BenutzerEinschreiberNummer 
FOREIGN KEY (BenutzerEinschreiberNummer) REFERENCES Benutzer(BenutzerNummer),
CONSTRAINT fk_KursNummer2 
FOREIGN KEY (KursNummer) REFERENCES Kurs(KursNummer),
PRIMARY KEY (EinschreibeID)
```

);

**The trigger looks like this, but it somehow doesn't work: **

```
CREATE TRIGGER erstellTrigger AFTER INSERT ON test.Kurs
          AS
          BEGIN
            INSERT INTO enschreiben VALUES 
              (NEW.BenutzerErstellerNummer, 
              NEW.KursNummer, 
              CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
              1);
END;
```

Comment: "Somehow doesn't work" and inconsistent database tags make the question quite unclear.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We're glad you're here. When you ask for some help, please help us by describing how your current code doesn't work. Does it return an error? If so, what is the exact error message? If not, what does it do that isn't what you expect? You'll get better answers if you help us to understand the problem. Also consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and other articles in the Help Center to get more out of using Stack Overflow.

Comment: Did you set delimiters? Also AS is incorrect in a mysql trigger and trigger is missing a for each row clause..

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting the values you need to specify which are the columns that the data is going to insert.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER erstellTrigger AFTER INSERT ON test.Kurs
              AS
              BEGIN
                INSERT INTO enschreiben(BenutzerEinschreiberNummer, KursNummer,Eintrittsdatum) VALUES 
                  (NEW.BenutzerErstellerNummer, 
                  NEW.KursNummer, 
                  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                  1);
    END;
```

This should work.

Comment: Not so you only need to specify column names if you are not inserting to all columns - although if is better to specify column names..

Answer (score 0):

The trigger is syntactically incorrect in mysql , AS is incorrect in a mysql trigger and trigger is missing a for each row clause..

This is syntactically correct and uses delimiters

```
drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER erstellTrigger AFTER INSERT ON Kurs
  for each row        
          BEGIN
            INSERT INTO enschreiben VALUES 
              (NEW.BenutzerErstellerNummer, 
              NEW.KursNummer, 
              CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
              1);
END $$
delimiter ;
```